# Efficient copy of a Map to a new Map in Scala

Tags: scala

My problem is the following:

```
for (something <- someotherthing) {
    val m = in._2 // gets a scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String] with already some values in it

    if (someotherotherthing) {
        m("item1") = "reset"
        m("item3") = "reset"
    }

    something :+= m
}
```

I go through something and get a map of string key value pairs. I want to only reset `item1` and `item3` in some cases. However when I run this, all of the maps that are added to `something` have these two `resets`. Can I copy this map to something else and then add it so that I don't edit all of the maps at once?

Comment: so, this is why I told you before: don't use mutable stuff. It's hard. Just pretend, that  everything is immutable, and rewrite your code with that in mind.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try that. I am still stuck in a different mindset while being new to Scala.

Comment: What's `in` anyway?

Comment: A tuple, where the first element is a .csv matrix and second element is my Map

Comment: I mean, where is it defined, and where it comes from. It looks like `m` references the same thing on every iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is some help for you!

```
val (someThing, inMap) = yourTuple
if (someBooleanCondition) {
  inMap.map {
    case (key, _) if key == "item1" => "item1" -> "reset"
    case (key, _) if key == "item3" => "item3" -> "reset"
    case (key, value) => key -> value
  }
}
```

Is this reasonable for you? There are a few concepts in my example which are:

1. How to unpack a Tuple
2. Use case block with if condition
3. Usage of partial function

I would recommend you understand these concepts before writing Scala! It will help you in the long run!

Comment: This code doesn't really do anything :) You gotta use the result of `.map` somehow ...

Comment: My intention was to give the original poster an idea on how to deal with immutable Map!

Comment: Note that if there are no keys `"item2"` and `"item3"` in the `inMap`, you won't set them. You might as well do `inMap ++ Map("item1" -> "reset", "item3" -> "reset")`

Comment: Yes, but the OP wants to set item1 and item2 based on a condition!

Comment: This is an interesting solution, thanks. Although I have decided to deal with immutable Maps throughout my program.

Comment: you can shorten e.g. `case (key, _) if key == "item1"` to just `case ("item1", _)`